# Does WhatsApp use asymmetric encryption?

Tags: encryption, asymmetric, whatsapp

I know that WhatsApp uses some kind of encryption to encrypt messages, but is it asymmetric encryption?

If not what kind of encryption does it use?

Comment: I know I did some grammatical mistakes but why I get so many down votes?

Comment: Most likely because the question seemed simple enough to search for on your own. Simply looking up "WhatsApp protocol" will answer that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WhatsApp uses the [Signal](https://signal.org/) protocol, which is outlined in the [Docs](https://signal.org/docs/), or in this [Whatsapp Security Whitepaper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf).

To answer your question, it uses both. Sessions are established via asymmetric cryptography (Curve25519) with users' public keys. Once a session is establish, symmetric cryptography (AES-CBC-256) is used along with hash authentication (HMAC-SHA256) to encrypt/decrypt and authenticate messages.

[Demystification article](https://medium.com/@justinomora/demystifying-the-signal-protocol-for-end-to-end-encryption-e2ee-ad6a567e6cb4)